# How to remove effect from a button?

Tags: objective-c, ipad

In my app for iPad. First I have a welcome screen. Screen has a custom button with an image. When I press that button, it shows some gray effect before moving to the next screen. I don't want that effect to appear. How can I remove that gray effect?

Regards
PC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the highlighted state of the UIButton. Per the [UIButton Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html) you can call `[button adjustsImageWhenHighlighted:NO];` to remove it.

Comment: Or, in Interface Builder, uncheck the "Highlighted Adjusts Image" box.

Answer (score 0):

Set the image for the button to nil for the Highlighted state.
[mybutton setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];